# How to create filtered data.frames based on names from a table?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm looking to use `names(table(data))` to generate a list of variables to apply a filter to subset a data.frame but don't know how to generate unique values for the data.frame names to save them.

```
Type <- c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A",
      "B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B",
      "C","C","C","C","C","C","C",
      "AB","AB","AB","AB","AB")
Type <- as.data.frame(Type)
```

This is how I'm generating the unique values I want:

```
type_names <- names(table(droplevels(Type$Type)))
```

This is my not-quite-there function:

```
library(dplyr)
NamedTypes <- function(data, nametype) {
  data %>% 
    filter(Type == nametype) %>% 
    a <- paste0(nametype, "_type")
}
```

Then how I think I'd run the function:

```
lapply(type_names, function(x) NamedTypes(Type, x))
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Comment: The output would just be filtered data.frames named respectively to the levels of the original data.frame. In the example, filtered data.frames named: A_type, B_type, C_type, AB_type.

Comment: you mean `split(Type, Type$Type)`?

Comment: Exactly but how do you set them as individual data.frames?

Comment: As your output, do you want an object containing (in this case) 4 data frames with different names, or do you want to create 4 new data frames in your environment?

Comment: what do you mean individual data frames? i.e. list them to your environment?

Comment: Programmatically subset the original data.frame into x new data.frames.

Comment: Save the split and Access the data.Frames individualy. `x <- split(Type,Type$Type)` `;` `x[["A"]]`

Comment: What @ count said is the typical suggestion here. Tossing DFs to the global environment for no reason will just create hassle for you later. Personally, I'd say: don't even split the original DF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `split` to create a list, and `list2env` to assign the data frames to your global environment

```
list2env(split(Type, Type$Type), globalenv())
```

Comment: Voted up for elegance and vectorization.

Comment: This is great. My only addition: list2env(split(Type, droplevels(Type$Type)), globalenv())

Comment: `list2env` is generally very bad practice. Better keep it in a list

Comment: @DavidArenburg I could not agree more. Not even splitting it (as Frank said).